# Как написать таймер корректно работающий в фоновом режиме

Tags: javascript

Написал такой таймер (незаконченный)

```
let seconds = prompt("Enter the number of minutes") * 60;
let showSeconds = seconds;
let minutes, house;
let time = document.querySelector('.time');

function spotZero(num) {
    if(num < 10) {
        return 0;
    }

    return "";
}

let timer = setTimeout(function tick() {
    seconds--;
    house = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
    minutes = Math.floor((seconds - house * 3600) / 60);
    showSeconds = seconds - house * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    time.innerHTML = `${spotZero(house)}${house}:${spotZero(minutes)}${minutes}:${spotZero(showSeconds)}${showSeconds}`

    setTimeout(tick, 1000)
}, 1000)
```

Проблема в том, что в фоновом режиме (если перейти в другую вкладку) таймер отстает. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отсчитывайте время не по количеству вызовов `setTimeout`, от начального значения `Date()`, сохраненного в переменную.